# Use multiple collections with MongoDB Kafka Connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

According with the documentation if you don't provide a value it will read from all collections

*"name of the collection in the database to watch for changes. If not set then all collections will be watched."*

I saw the connector source code and I confirmed this:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka/blob/k133/src/main/java/com/mongodb/kafka/connect/source/MongoSourceTask.java#L462

However if the collection is not provided I got an error like this:

```
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=mongo-source-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:186)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 73 (InvalidNamespace): '{aggregate: 1} is not valid for '$changeStream'; a collection is required.' on server localhost:27018. The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1603928795, "i": 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "{aggregate: 1} is not valid for '$changeStream'; a collection is required.", "code": 73, "codeName": "InvalidNamespace", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1603928795, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type": "00"}, "keyId": {"$numberLong": "0"}}}}
```

This is my configuration file

```
name=mongo-source
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
tasks.max=1

# Connection and source configuration
connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27018/order
database=order
collection=

topic.prefix=redemption
poll.max.batch.size=1000
poll.await.time.ms=5000

# Change stream options
pipeline=[]
batch.size=0
change.stream.full.document=updateLookup
collation=
copy.existing=true
errors.tolerance=all
```

If a collection is used, I'm able to use the connector and generate topics.

Seeing the logs it appears the connector is connecting to the db:

*INFO Watching for database changes on 'order' (com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask:620)*

Source Code

```
else if (collection.isEmpty()) {
      LOGGER.info("Watching for database changes on '{}'", database);
      MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(database);
      changeStream = pipeline.map(db::watch).orElse(db.watch());
    } else
```

If I go to my mongo console, I'm having the following:

```
rs0:SECONDARY> db.watch()
2020-10-28T18:13:50.344-0600 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: db.watch is not a function :
@(shell):1:1
rs0:SECONDARY> db.watch
test.watch
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using mongo 3.6 version which supports to watch collections but doesn't support to watch databases or deployments (instances), therefore I was getting those errors.

I found this on the documentation:

> Starting in MongoDB 4.0, you can open a change stream cursor for a single database (excluding admin, local, and config database) to watch for changes to all its non-system collections.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#watch-collection-database-deployment

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to multiple [change streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/usage-examples/multiple-sources/) from multiple mongo collections. You just need to provide the Regex for the collection names in `pipeline`, you can even provide the Regex for database names if you have multiple databases to listen to.

```
"pipeline": "[{\"$match\":{\"$and\":[{\"ns.db\":{\"$regex\":/^database-name$/}},{\"ns.coll\":{\"$regex\":/^collections_.*/}}]}}]"
```

You can even exclude any given database using `$nin`, which you dont want to listen for any change-stream.

```json
"pipeline": "[{\"$match\":{\"$and\":[{\"ns.db\":{\"$regex\":/^database-name$/,\"$nin\":[/^any_database_name$/]}},{\"ns.coll\":{\"$regex\":/^collections_.*/}}]}}]"
```

Here is the complete Kafka connector configuration.

***Mongo to Kafka source connector***

```
{
  "name": "mongo-to-kafka-connect",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "publish.full.document.only": "true",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "topic.creation.enable": "true",
    "poll.await.time.ms": 1000,
    "poll.max.batch.size": 100,
    "topic.prefix": "any prefix for topic name",
    "output.json.formatter": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://<username>:<password>@ip:27017,ip:27017,ip:27017,ip:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=xyz&tls=true",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "copy.existing": "true",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 3,
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": 3,
    "topic.creation.compacted.cleanup.policy": "compact",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "mongo.errors.log.enable": "true",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": 10000,
    "pipeline": "[{\"$match\":{\"$and\":[{\"ns.db\":{\"$regex\":/^database-name$/}},{\"ns.coll\":{\"$regex\":/^collections_.*/}}]}}]"
  }
}
```

You can get more details from official docs.

- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/
- https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html

Comment: Listen for Changes on Multiple Sources (Mongo Kafka connector): https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/v1.11/source-connector/usage-examples/multiple-sources/#listen-for-changes-on-multiple-sources.